# webdriver keeps throwing IOException and reconnecting

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am using webdriver api (Selenium) and when I am trying to test a site (which I can view and browse normally in my browsers), I get the following message over and over.

```
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect
18-Aug-2010 12:36:08 AM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
```

Why do I keep getting this error ?

Comment: Please add further information: source code of the test, version of Selenium, where the test is ran from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to configure a proxy. I get the same error if none is configured.

If you use the `HtmlUnitDriver` (You have to use the concrete implementation of `WebDriver` to access the `setProxy` method:

```
HtmlUnitDriver d = new HtmlUnitDriver();
d.setProxy("your.proxy.here", proxyPort);
```

If you use the `FirefoxDriver`:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("your.proxy.here:proxyPort");
firefoxProfile.setProxyPreferences(proxy);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Comment: hi I don't understand why I need a proxy because I am trying to run the test on my application and my computer IP is not blocked.

Comment: Then please give us more information. See comment at the top.

Comment: I understand now. I realized the application was loading advertisements that was lagging out. do I always have to specify a firefox profile for each instances ? if I want to run multiple firefox instances, can I use the same profile ?